# How do I interpret my residual plots for my generalized additive model created in R?

Tags: r, statistics, gam

I've created a generalized additive model in R and I'm having some issues interpreting the residual plots. Specifically, the Residuals vs linear predictor plot and the observed vs. fitted values plot. I've attached my model code, summary and residual plots below.

I've googled how to interpret the plots however most of them focus on generalized linear models and not general additive models.

```
modG<-gam(mn_logHPE ~s(DOY, bs = "tp", k = 307) +s(TAG, k = 3, bs = "re"),
          data = LTRdat3, method = "REML", family = Gamma(link = "log"))

plot(modG)
summary(modG)
```

[image]
[image]appraise(modG)

Comment: If you need help interpreting results from statistical models, you should ask for help at [stats.se] instead. You are likely to get better help there. This is not really a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why do you think that 306 basis functions are needed for the DOTY effect? Also, you can’t constrain the basis dimension of a random effect smooth as you tried to here; it used k=5 despite what you asked for. If you post this on CV, pop back here and post the link and I’ll add an answer; but basically it looks like you are missing something structural (the residuals have a bend in them), but that might be do to many things. Plot the residuals against covariates to see what might be going; you might have different DOY effects in each TAG for example